# Extending a Django Template and Overriding Blocks in a Loop

Tags: django, templates

**EDIT**

So it turns out that the example below will work if you move the extends tag above the comment tags.  Per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance): "If you use {% extends %} in a template, it must be the first template tag in that template. Template inheritance won’t work, otherwise."

**Original Question:**

I'm still fairly new to Django so I did some Googling but wasn't able to find anything that helped.  Apologies if this is a duplicate!

**Scenario**

Let's say I have a number of different models that share the same superclass, and I want to display all of their common fields in a partial:

```
    {% comment %}
        Template: 
            _model_attribute_list.html
        Args:
            models: A collection of models that inherit from the same superclass
    {% endcomment %}

    {% for model in models %}
      <ul>
        <li>Common Attribute 1: {{ model.common_attribute_1 }}</li>
        <li>Common Attribute 2: {{ model.common_attribute_2 }}</li>
        <li>Common Attribute 3: {{ model.common_attribute_3 }}</li>
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

Easy enough.  Now I'm interested in showing not only those attributes, but also attributes that are specific to particular models.  Instead of duplicating that partial N times, I'd like to add blocks:

```
    {% comment %}
        Template: 
            _model_attribute_list.html (with blocks added)
        Args:
            models: A collection of models that inherit from the same superclass
    {% endcomment %}

    {% for model in models %}
      <ul>
        {% block leading_attributes %}{% endblock %}
        <li>Common Attribute 1: {{ model.common_attribute_1 }}</li>
        <li>Common Attribute 2: {{ model.common_attribute_2 }}</li>
        <li>Common Attribute 3: {{ model.common_attribute_3 }}</li>
        {% block trailing_attributes %}{% endblock %}
      </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

and have the other model specific partials override them so they can include custom fields:

```
    {% comment %}
        Template: 
            _model1_attribute_list.html
        Args:
            models: A collection of Model1
    {% endcomment %}
    {% extends '_model_attribute_list.html' %}

    {% block leading_attributes %}
        <li>Custom Attribute 1: {{ model.custom_attribute_1 }}</li>
        <li>Custom Attribute 2: {{ model.custom_attribute_2 }}</li>
    {% endblock %}
```

According to the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#template-inheritance), when extending a template:

> ...the template engine will notice the...block tags in [the parent template] and replace those blocks with the contents of the child template

Given what the docs say, why doesn't this work?

My hypothesis is that when the templating engine renders the template, it inserts the blocks before the loop is evaluated, resulting in an error since the values for `model.custom_aatribute_N` do not exist yet.

Additionally, I don't actually see any errors, but the template doesn't get rendered.  Is there a way to make Django spit out errors in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your current setup is working, but here is another way that you can try.

- Create common template with appropriate blocks that you want
- Create specialized templates as per your pages
- In page, instead of extending the template, include the template.

For example:

base.html

```
  <ul>
    {% block leading_attributes %}{% endblock %}
    <li>Common Attribute 1: {{ model.common_attribute_1 }}</li>
    <li>Common Attribute 2: {{ model.common_attribute_2 }}</li>
    <li>Common Attribute 3: {{ model.common_attribute_3 }}</li>
    {% block trailing_attributes %}{% endblock %}
  </ul>
```

special1.html

```
{%extends "base.html" %}
{% block leading_attributes %}
    <li>Custom Attribute 1: {{ model.custom_attribute_1 }}</li>
    <li>Custom Attribute 2: {{ model.custom_attribute_2 }}</li>
{% endblock %}
```

your_page.html

```
{% for model in models %}
    {%include "special1.html" %}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: I figured it out, and it turns out my example would work...if I moved the "extends" tag before the comments.  Boy do I feel silly!  Anyways, I'm going to mark you as the correct answer since you took the time to help me out.  Thanks for your help!